# Quick Search for a Person's name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I was curious to know about the best quick search query that is used to retrieve a person's info. Currently, we have a database which has columns for first name, last name and salutation. The user should be allowed to search for any permutation and combination of these columns. The simple search query is taking a lot of time and thus making this quick search slow (As the query needs to scan all the rows for first name, last name and salutation). Could you please share the various fast or advanced techniques that could be used for this purpose.

Comment: Is this a prefix search, or a direct comparison?

Comment: How many rows in the table? How many rows in the search results? (All of them or paginated?) What is the selectivity of salutation? I presume some values are very common such as "Mr" and others less so (e.g. "Dr")?

Comment: 4601802 rows are there. Yes, these values are common, in this case we show top 200 rows

Comment: It is a direct comparison for firstname or last name along with salutation (optional)

Answer (score 2):

I think Full-text search should solve your problem (Supposing the database is MS SQL Server)
A quick link for your reference http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

***I could not comment on the question because my reputation is low***

Comment: FTS (using CONTAINS) will be faster/more efficient than using LIKE with wildcarding. FTS includes the ability to define Full Text Indexes, which FTS can use.LIKE with wildcarding on the left side (IE: LIKE '%Search') can not use an index (assuming one exists for the column), guaranteeing a table scan. I haven't tested & compared, but regex has the same pitfall. To clarify, LIKE '%Search' and LIKE '%Search%' can not use an index; LIKE 'Search%' can use an index, which i am currently using in my query.

Answer (score 1):

1.You can create indexes for the column which u think is going to be searched most of the time.
2.You can combine the first name+last name and keep in a view(and this view shall e updated for every insert of name),and then query through this view rather than querying through the database.
You need a proper query execution plan.Check these one out for a strategic solution
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/

Comment: Combining first name and last name provides no benefits for searchability here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create index on these 3 columns firstname,lastname and salutation so by creating index it will search the fast so for performance point of query we create index.index are very faster. for learn about speed up your query [click here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/199058/SQL-Server-Indexed-Views-Speed-Up-Your-Select-Quer)

Comment: The article you linked is about indexed views. They won't be any more beneficial than normal indexes.